# using (Html.BeginForm()) on button submit to send an object of type CategoriesLanguages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax.beginform

Hello as I'm so new to Mvc I woild appreciate any Help!

So Here is myModels

**Category**

-CategoryID

-DateCreated

---

**CategoriesLanguages**

- ID (autoincrement)
- CategoryID
- LanguageID
- Title
- Description

Basically I want to be able when I click AddNew Button - I create a new record in Category table - and I'm having the id of the created category.
And in the Create() view which Create() action is returning I gave the user opportunity to fill the description and title of categorylanguages.

ANd when the user clicks the submit button he should be redirected to Create(CategoryLanguages) acton which as you see accepts an object of CategoryLanguage and this action will simply store  this object in the database. My QUESTION IS HOW TO RETURN this object!

```
public class CategoryController : Controller
    {


        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            CategoryViewModel vm = new CategoryViewModel();
            vm.AddNewCategory();
            return View(vm);
        }
          pubcli AcrionResult Create(CategoryLanguage ob)
          {
              CategoryViewModel vm = new CategoryViewModel();
              vm.SaveInDatabaseCategorylanguage(ob);
              return RedirectToAction("Index");

          }
}
```

And Here is my View CreateView.csHtml

```
 @model MvcApplication1.ViewModel.CategoryViewModel

  /
  @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
  {

    <fieldset class="form-horizontal">
        <legend>Category</legend>

        // Here i should have a dropdpwn and teh selected value I should get it for LanguageID

        <div class="control-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.modelcatlang.Title, new { @class = "control-label" })
            <div class="controls">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.modelcatlang.Title) //From here i should get title

            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="control-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.modelcatlang.Description, new { @class = "control-label" })
            <div class="controls">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.modelcatlang.Description) //from here I should get the description
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-actions no-color">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn" />

/*somehow ewhen i click this button I should make 

CategoryLanguage  catlang= new CategoryLanguahe;

catLang.CatID = insertedID (I have it nio problem);

catlang.lanID = dropdown.value;

catlang.Title = from title from editorform
...*/

        </div>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

---

**EDIT**

I'm posting the code for My CategoryViewModel

```
public class CategoryViewModel
    {
        public CategoryLanguages modelcatlang { get; set; }
        public int newCategoryID { get; set; }
        public List<Language> lstLanguages { get; set; }
        public List<CategoryLanguages> lstCategoryLanguages { get; set; }
        public CategoryLanguages categoryToEdit { get; set; }
        private readonly ICategoryRepository catRep;
        private readonly ILanguageRepository lanRep;
        private readonly ICategoryLanguageRepository catlanRep;
        public CategoryViewModel()
            : this(new CategoryRepository(), new LanguageRepository(), new CategoryLanguageRepository())
        {

        }

        public CategoryViewModel(ICategoryRepository catRep, ILanguageRepository lanRep, ICategoryLanguageRepository catlanRep)
        {
            this.catRep = catRep;
            this.lanRep = lanRep;
            this.catlanRep = catlanRep;
        }


        public void AddNewCategory()
        {
            lstLanguages = lanRep.GetAllAvailableLanguages();
            newCategoryID = catRep.AddCategory();
            modelcatlang = new CategoryLanguages();
        }
```

---

So in the  ViewModel in AddNewCategory() Method i have the id of the just inserted Category in category table (in newCategoryID)
I also make an instance of CategoryLanguage().SO maybe my new question will be - how can i fill all the properties of modelcatlang object(part of my viewmodel) and return it to Create(CategoriesLanguages) action

Comment: it's a little bit confused! you want to add category and the related language in one submit button?

Comment: You can't have "two forms". You can only get one view model from your post action. For now, you declared your model as `MvcApplication1.ViewModel.CategoryViewModel` and this is the type that will get posted in your `Create` action (the second one and add an `[HttpPost]` attribute to it).

Comment: SO what do you think - how can I achieve what I want!

Comment: One way is to merge the two view models: add all the properties from your `CategoryLanguage ` (i.e. `CatID`, `lanID`, `Title`) to `CategoryViewModel`.

Comment: Hi ANdrei - i also posted the code of my viewmodel. Can you see it